# thrust::sort missorts some values

Tags: c++, sorting, thrust

I have some objects I want to sort on a host_vector, These objects have a < Operator defined, which compares the Id (a integer) of the objects. The vector contains pointers to the objects.

If I perform `thrust::sort(object_vector.begin(),object_vector.end());` and then iterate through the vector to print the Id's I get:
`48, 49, 0, 1, [..], 47, 50, [..]`

If I perform `std::sort(object_vector.begin(),object_vector.end());`
I get the Id's in order. I have no clue why these two values are out of order (they are always the same for the same number of objects).
The objects according to this Id's have nothing special.

stable_sort doesn't change anything.
Sorting a vector with the Id's works.
Operators:

```
bool operator<(MultiLegBase* other){return (this->getID()<other->getID());}
bool operator==(MultiLegBase* other){return this->getID()==other->getID();}
bool operator>(MultiLegBase* other){return this->getID()>other->getID();}
virtual unsigned int const getID(return m_Id;)
```

Comment: What happens if you first create a vector of just the integer ids, and then `thrust::sort` that? If it works, either your `operator<` or your `operator=` are probably faulty.

Comment: Show us the relevant code for your object

Comment: Provide a complete reproducer.  It shouldn't be that hard to do.  In the process of creating the reproducer, you may well discover the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I looked  again on my operators and got what is wrong. The `this->getID()`  construct fails. Because `operator>()`, is not called with two pointer arguments (as far as I understand).
I solved it with an functor:
`[..] bool operator()(Multibaseleg* M,Multibaseleg* N){return (M->getID()<N->getID());}[..]`